# CSS: Responsive, background image issue

Tags: html, css

I can't get the image to appear, which is bizarre as the div box is there when I highlight elements on the page. Also no issues with validation/inspection.

html:

```
<div class="mainImage"></div>
```

css:

```
.mainImage {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(Images\top.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Attempted:

- Forward slash filepath
- Quotes ' and "
- Both background declarations in the same statement

The link is correct, tested.

Thank you.

Comment: ~\Images\top.jpg or ..\

Comment: url(..\Images\top.jpg); ?

Comment: use `background-image: url(Images/top.jpg);`

Comment: We can't give a definitive answer without knowing where the image is in relation to the CSS file. Try an absolute URL. If that works, it's your path that's faulty. If not, perhaps naming of file/folder (capitals often matter, for example, so preferably never use them in file names or paths).

Comment: folder called Image in the root, seems obvious.

Comment: Then that's your problem. Unless the CSS file is also in the root folder, the path is wrong. And `/Image/` is not the same as `/Images/`. According to your last comment, the path should be `url(/Image/top.jpg)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.mainImage {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('Images/top.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

this works for me

Comment: body { background-color: #A5937A; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; } is the only other style that correlates with this one.

Comment: your html file is in same directory as your Images folder correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
background-image: url("Images/top.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the Image folder exist? Is it in the same path your HTML file is? and did you "connect" the css to the html file? the only attribute that does not work is the image? Did you check that the image is JPG?
Maybe try to set some fixed width, maybe give some background color (background-color: red;), then we can find where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

```
.mainImage {
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url('../Images/top.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
```

Put ../ before the path.